# Microsoft Chart Controls legend

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-chart-controls

Using [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422), is it possible to be able to remove a series from a chart by clicking on it in the legend, or do I have to create a separate control for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event handler call the HitTest and if it is Legenditem remove the series.

Answer (score 0):

Handling the click event may solve the problem but leads to a confusing UI. You may need a special control with some checkbox beside each series. [MSChartWrapper](https://github.com/sinairv/MSChartWrapper) may solve this problem.